# C# Regular expressions find and replace links with only uppercase characters and don't match exclusions

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having a hard time with what seems to be a simple Regex task. I'd like to replace all href links within text that have uppercase character with lowercase with the following exclusions.

For example

`href="/image-ZOOM.aspx?UPPERcasE=someThing"` match and replace to

`href="/image-zoom.aspx?uppercase=something"`

`href="/image-coorect.aspx"` - would not match

Also it would exclude `href="javascript:function();"` and would not lowercase anything between `<% %>` tags.

For example:

`href="/images/PDFs/<%=Product.ShortSku %>.pdf"` gets translated into

`href="/images/**pdfs**/<%=Product.ShortSku %>.pdf"`

I've tried something like `href="([^"]*[A-Z]+[^"]*)"` but that still matches links with all lowercase. Could you please shine some light.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are just converting to lowercase, then why does it matter if it matches links that are already in lowercase?  Effectively nothing would happen to it anyway.

Comment: The pattern you give doesn't match href="/image-coorect.aspx" for me.  Can you show your test code?

Comment: That's true but when I have <% %> inside the link I don't want it to be converted to lowercase

Comment: I don't have test code yet, I'm testing using Quick find in visual studio with regular expressions

Comment: @McLovin does your question revolve around C# or using Visual Studio's Find/Replace with regex? They are completely different so clarification is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tricky part is your `<% ... %>` requirement. It's actually pretty simple once you break each part of the URL into groups.

```
href="/images/PDFs/<%=Product.ShortSku %>.pdf"
      |_____1_____||__________2_________||_3_|
```

1. This group must exist.
2. This group is optional.
3. If group 2 doesn't exist then group 3 won't exist, in which case group 1 matches the entire href content. If group 2 exists, group 3 will be the remainder of the href content.

By understanding the above you end up with this for other strings:

```
href="/image-ZOOM.aspx?UPPERcasE=someThing"
      |________________1_________________|
```

I ended up with this pattern which makes use of named groups:

```
@"href=""(?!javascript:)(?=[^""]*[A-Z])(?<Start>[^""<]+)(?<Special><%[^""]+%>)?(?<End>[^""]*)"""
```

- `href=""` : matches href and opening double-quote.
- `(?!javascript:)` : negative look-ahead to ignore javascript functions.
- `(?=[^""]*[A-Z])` : positive look-ahead to find uppercase letters in the content to come. The `[^""]*` matches any char that isn't a double-quote. This is done to avoid going past the end of the content and greedily matching unintended content.
- `(?<Start>[^""<]+)` : named group that matches any char as long as it is not a double-quote or opening angle bracket. Look at the earlier depiction - the angle bracket check ensures we stop if `<% ... %>` content is encountered. If it doesn't the pattern will continue till it encounters the closing double-quote.
- `(?<Special><%[^""]+%>)?` : **optional** named group to capture `<% ... %>` content. The trailing `?` marks this entire group as optional.
- `(?<End>[^""]*)` : named group to match any remaining content. Notice here I use `*` to make it match zero or more content. This allows this portion of the pattern to act as an optional match in the case where the *Special* group doesn't exist.
- `""` : closing double-quote.

Sample code:

```
string[] inputs =
{
    "href=\"/image-ZOOM.aspx?UPPERcasE=someThing\"", // match
    "href=\"/image-coorect.aspx\"",  // no match, lowercase
    "href=\"javascript:function();\"", // no match, javascript
    "href=\"/images/PDFs/<%=Product.ShortSku %>.pDf\"", // bypass <% %> content
};

string pattern = @"href=""(?!javascript:)(?=[^""]*[A-Z])(?<Start>[^""<]+)(?<Special><%[^""]+%>)?(?<End>[^""]*)""";

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,6}: {1}", Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern), input);
    string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,
                        m => "href=\""
                            + m.Groups["Start"].Value.ToLower()
                            + m.Groups["Special"].Value
                            + m.Groups["End"].Value.ToLower()
                            + "\"");
    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This uses a lambda in place of the `MatchEvaluator`. Essentially we are reconstructing the string and referring to the named groups, altering the case on the groups we want to modify. The subtle key to this code is that if a group didn't match we can still reference it and it'll simply give us an empty string. Also, this might not be obvious from the code, but when a match fails the original string is returned unaltered by `Regex.Replace`.

Comment: What happens if you have letters that aren’t `[A-Z]`?

Comment: @tchrist the `[A-Z]` is only used to match content where uppercase letters appear. If none exist, the match fails and no replacement occurs. If they do exist then the pattern really matches on `[^""]+`, i.e., everything that is not a double-quote. Ultimately the `ToLower()` call will affect all letters in a match.

Comment: Wow thank you very much Ahmad, very informative answer and very detailed! What would you do if you didn't know how many exclusions with <% %> you had in your strings for example if href contains 2 or 3 expressions within <% %> tags

Comment: @McLovin it looks like [climbage's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220722/c-regular-expressions-negative-lookahead-exclude-from-match/4221562#4221562) to your other question handles that scenario very well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're using the "/i" modifier, make sure that you're not using "RegexOptions.IgnoreCase"

```
   List<string> list = new List<string>() {
        "href=\"/image-ZOOM.aspx?UPPERcasE=someThing\"",
        "href=\"/image-zoom.aspx?uppercase=something\"",
        "href=\"/image-coorect.aspx\"",
        "href=\"javascript:function();\"" 
    };

    foreach (string l in list) 
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(l, "href=\"([^\"]*[A-Z]+[^\"]*)\"")) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(l);
        }
    }
```

Will only match: href="/image-ZOOM.aspx?UPPERcasE=someThing"

Comment: That's great thanks, but how do I exclude <% content %> from the match?

Comment: Thank goodness URLs aren’t allowed to be anything but ASCII! (?)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm confused. If you have a collection of controls and or tags on your page, you can test them to see if they are anchor types, and if so, you can get the href attribute from the tag, then set the href to href.ToLower ...

Is there a particular *reason* to use a regex to solve a string and DOM parsing problem? Seems like overkill to me.

Comment: yea there is a reason, I have an old solution with 2000+ aspx files and I need to make all links lowercase automatically

Comment: @McLovin ~ So are you doing this in Visual Studio then or the app? If in the app write a module for IIS. For that matter, if you're on IIS, what does case matter?