# C# Regular expressions negative lookahead exclude from match

Tags: c#, regex

somewhere in the text I have an a link with href

```
  <a href="image-CoRRECTME.aspx?ALSO=ME&leaveme=<%= MyClass.Text %>">somelink</a>
```

I need to replace text in href attribue to lowercase except content of the <% %> brakets

should look like:

```
 <a href="image-correctme.aspx?also=me&leaveme=<%= MyClass.Text %>">somelink</a>
```

I was thinking something like this.. `"href=\"([^\"]*[A-Z]+[^\"]*)(?:(?<!.*<%[^%]*%>.*)))\""` but its not working.

Thanks!

Comment: whoa whoa, slow down. Are you actually parsing the aspx file? Or you're actually executing that page and trying to replace whatever value is in href through the code behind? Where are you going to place that regex replacement?

Comment: I just need to make text in links lowercase that's all

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Regular expressions find and replace links with only uppercase characters and don't match exclusions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219017/c-regular-expressions-find-and-replace-links-with-only-uppercase-characters-and)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this if you haven't figured it out already.

```
private void test()
{
    string t = @"<a href=""image-CoRRECTME.aspx?ALSO=ME&leaveme=<%= MyClass.Text %>&test2=<%= MyClass2.Text %>&last_test=nothing"">somelink</a>";
    string fixed_string = Regex.Replace(t, "(?<=href=\"|href=\"[^\"]*%>)([^\"]*?)(?=<%|\")", TestMatchEvaluator);
}

private string TestMatchEvaluator(Match m)
{
    return m.Value.ToLower();
}
```

Comment: +1 nice work. I took a different approach in [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219017/c-regular-expressions-find-and-replace-links-with-only-uppercase-characters-and/4221722#4221722) to the OP's other question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you...

```
Regex test = new Regex(@"(?<=(href\=""))[^<]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

string htmlCode = @"<a href=""image-CoRRECTME.aspx?ALSO=ME&leaveme=<%= MyClass.Text %>"">somelink</a>";

string result = test.Replace(htmlCode, test.Match(htmlCode).Value.ToLower());
```

Comment: Argument exception parsing "?<=(href\="))[^"]+" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.

Comment: I was missing a paren. Fixed now.

Comment: Ryan, this also makes text in the <% %> brackets lowercase, my question was how to exclude it from the match

Comment: @McLovin, I somehow missed that earlier. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Ryan, this I'm sorry but the brackets could be anywhere in the strings for example @"<a href=""image-CoRRECTME.aspx?leaveme=<%= MyClass.Text %>&ALSO=ME"">somelink</a>"; would not work